# Libgdx - not implementing Screen

Tags: android, libgdx

```
public class MenuState extends State {
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private Viewport viewport;
private MenuButtons playButton;

public MenuState(GameStateManager gsm, int tryscore, AssetsClass assetsClass, PreferencesHelper preferencesHelper) {
    super(gsm);

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new FitViewport(ButtonCrash.V_WIDTH, ButtonCrash.V_HEIGHT, camera);
    viewport.apply();

    playButton = new MenuButtons(assetsClass.getManager().get("mainmenu/button_play.png", Texture.class), 1);
    playButton.getButton().setSize(200, 200);
    playButton.getButton().setPosition(-100, -100);
}
@Override
protected void handlingInput() {

}

@Override
public void update(float delta) {
    camera.update();
}

@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    sb.begin();
    playButton.getButton().draw(sb);
    sb.end();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}
```

}

And well the camera works nice, but the viewports don't, it is like they are not there!

I actually copied everything about the code I even tried in constructor:

```
viewport.update(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

But it seems as like because I am not implementing the Screen the code doesn't work. The thing is I made my game without Game and Screen interface, but made my own State class. What might be the problem here?

Comment: Any specific reason you made your own state class when LibGdx ahs a great one?

Comment: Make sure you call viewport.update in the resize method. Looks like your State class needs one.

Comment: Do you have `resize()` method implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply the viewport before rendering, as far as I know.
So put

```
viewport.apply();
```

at the beginning of your render(); before you set the matrix.

cheers